# Spring boot default security authentication from other port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, development-environment

For quickly development Frontend (React) works on port 3000.
CORS Request working well.
I get the problem with authentication from frontend:

- small problem 1 is redirection on port 8080
- **big problem 2 that authentication is successful but on port 8080**

i just wont have successful authentication while runing react frontend.localhost:3000 .
not use Spring-mvc .

server successful wenn frontend also on 8080 port.

`HTTP/1.1 302
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8AA9C90B5599372059183C6D94798609; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 17:26:41 GMT`

server fail response wenn frontend on 3000 port.

`HTTP/1.1 302
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6AE3EA77D7786281DE5F2E9FE2EC2A31; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 17:30:53 GMT`

###ADDITIONAL:
So a find solution by myself. 3 days and 5 lines of code*(
fixing of redirection problem :

```
<code>
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                //allow not authenticated user access to login page
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                //give access all users to React resources
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //enable redirect to login if user not authenticated
.and().formLogin().successHandler(corsAuthSuccessHandler()).loginPage("/login")
              .and().csrf().disable();
    }

@Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler corsAuthSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
                if (request.getHeader("Origin").equals(frontEndDevDomain))
                    return request.getHeader("Origin");
                return super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);
            }
        };
//Cors header allover:  
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins(frontEndDevDomain)
                    .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
</code>
```

From frontend after login every request will be CORS, if u use fetch just add the line  credentials: 'include'
For Example :  `fetch(URL + '/api/company/add/?name=' + name, {method: 'POST', credentials: 'include'})`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you are facing? Are you using spring MVC with Spring Boot? How are you authenticating and how does your backend respond?

Comment: sure. i just added specification.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral how setup development of  project if backend not working with frontend on other port(namely authentication)? it's take too mach time build frontend end restart backend very time.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral it works well except authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is caused by client side cors policy.
Adding some parameters on your ajax call could help.
If you are using the fetch apifor example, try to include credentials:"include" in the request options.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks . u are right . redirection after login to server origin, and frontend request with credentials.